# What is the recommended way to log a Spring Boot web app?

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have developed a web app with Spring Boot. I have deployed it on AWS ElasticBeanstalk.
I'm now working on a logging system based on SpringAOP. I created an aspect which intercept all the methods call of classes mapped by @Service, @Repository and @Controller. This is the class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * Pointcut that matches all repositories, services and Web REST endpoints.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)" +
            " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)" +
            " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut that matches all Spring beans in the application's main packages.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.mywebapp..*)" +
            " || within(com.mywebapp.service..*)" +
            " || within(com.mywebapp.controller..*)")
    public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    /**
     * Advice that logs methods throwing exceptions.
     *
     * @param joinPoint join point for advice
     * @param e exception
     */
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
        String s = "";
        if(joinPoint.getArgs() != null)
            s = Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
        log.error("Exception in {}.{}({}) with cause = {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                s,
                e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : "NULL");
    }

    /**
     * Advice that logs when a method is entered and exited.
     *
     * @param joinPoint join point for advice
     * @return result
     * @throws Throwable throws IllegalArgumentException
     */
    @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        if(request != null && joinPoint.getSignature().toString().contains("controller")){
            log.info("Request: {} {} from {}",
                    request.getMethod(),
                    request.getRequestURI(),
                    request.getRemoteAddr());
        }
        log.info("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
            String printResult = "";
            if(result instanceof InputStream)
                printResult = "InputStream type found!";
            else
                printResult = result.toString();

            log.info("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), printResult);
            return result;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("Illegal argument: {} in {}.{}()", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. I can see inside the log all the information. Now my question is: what is the best practice to save all these information? Is it enough to save them inside the default Spring log file or it's better if I create a NoSql document and save all these information formatted in a more readable manner.
For instance I created this simple object which can be used to store this information in a better way using mongodb:

```
@Document
public class LogEvent {
    private String requestUrl;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String type;
    private String message;

    public LogEvent(String requestUrl, String ipAddress, String type, String message) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

*type* will be "error" or "info" and *message* will be the signature the name the args and the result of each method call, so for instance:

```
Request: GET /pages/who-is from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Enter: com.mywebapp.controller.PageController.getWhoIs() with argument[s] = [] 
Exit: com.mywebapp.controller.PageController.getWhoIs() with result = who-is
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be digging through server log files and grepping text files, it's much better to get your application produced logs off of servers and into some sort of storage that allows you to query, aggregate and generally work with in a well defined and understood way. Storing it in Mongo as you mention is possible, but there are a number of other solutions to this.

Then the question is, do you want to run and manage your own log management stack or do you want to use a managed service? Do you want to pay for the service, or pay for it with  your own time? How critical is it that your logs have high availability? For example, in your Mongo example, if Mongo has an outage are you blind to your application logging? Is this OK? What's an acceptable level of end-to-end latency from a log being generated to be able to query and report on? The answers to those will help drive your approach...

There are many logging-as-a-service offers (https://stackify.com/best-log-management-tools/), and depending on your expected data volumes and what this is for (any security requirements etc) these might do for you. For getting the data off of the application and into the storage, [FluentD](https://www.fluentd.org/) is a well adopted approach that allows you to control log schema and integates well with most solutions.

There are also fully managed services, such as Azure application insights for Java, https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/tree/master/azure-application-insights-spring-boot-starter, where the collection of and management of data is all done for you, you just pay per GB of data you ingress.

I'd recommend looking into one of the free offerings and seeing if any of them meets your requirements - I've used successfully in small, non-critical applications.

Where data size is larger & latency time and availability requirements are stricter, I prefer a managed service as it's a big data problem and I don't want to be managing Terabytes of data - I'd rather someone does that for me :)